# IIF Statment returning false part in SSRS 2005

Tags: reportingservices-2005

Below is the VB Expression Code for a field in my SSRS 2005 Report. This Expression Code returns only the False Part of the `IIF Statement`. But there is no reason why it should not return the true part as it is Referencing the correct colomn which contains data.

VB CODE

```
=IIF(CBOOL(Fields!OverallCPT.Value) = TRUE OR Fields!OverallCPT.Value > 0 OR Fields!OverallCPT.Value <> 0,
FORMAT((AVG(Fields!CPT_Time.Value) / 60000),"00") & ":" & FORMAT((AVG(Fields!CPT_Time.Value) mod 60000/1000),"00") ,Nothing)
```

Below is parts of the dataset I am using to get the data into a usable format.

SQL DATA SET CODE

```
Convert(Bigint,DatePart(minute,[Arrival Time]) * 60000) + Convert(Bigint,Datepart(second,[Arrival Time])*1000) AS 'CPT Time'
```

Why would this `IIF statement` return false when the Data Set returns a value for the conditions I supply in the `IIF Statement`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your IIF for debugging purposes to this:

```
=IIF(TRUE,1,0)
```

If you are still getting unexpected results, I would suggest that your "true" and "false" outcomes may be in the wrong positions. (You did not specify which you intended to get back when the condition is true - the proper syntax is if condition first, then true outcome, and finally false outcome)

If not, then you have a bug in either your if condition, or in your calculations of OverallCPT. You may also want to verify that [Arrival Time] contains the value(s) you expect. Your if condition looks syntactically correct, but I can't be certain that it's what you intended it to be without more information.